# QGIS auto fill with increments

Tags: qgis, function

i want a shapefile table to be autofilled,for example each new point i place has an attribute column that auto fills its self a set of repeated numbers such as (1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,...etc)

and another column to have a string and numbers and the numbers would increase 
(a1a1,a1a2,a1a3,a1a4,a1a2,a2a2,...etc) and so on, and if one value gets deleted i can relace it without the entire data shifting

Is there a function for those things?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @AbdullahAlaa! Your first part can be solved using the expression `($rownum - 1) % 4 + 1`. Your second part though, is `a1a1,a1a2,a1a3,a1a4` supposed to repeat? Just noticed that you also included `a1a2,a2a2`, is `a2a2` a mistake?

Comment: Thank you for the $rowrun function

as for the second part it is meant to repeat and increase  (a1a1,a1a2,a1a3,a1a4,a2a1,a2a2,a2a3.a2a4.a3a1.a3a2.a3a3.a3a4 and so)
also is there a function to change a string so that not only span the numbers from 1-4 but also the letters from a-z

Comment: also is there a way to update the data those functions created automatically